# Проблема с Flask Restfull выводом картинок

Tags: python, rest, flask

Пишу простое API для управления умным домом. Хочу иметь возможность получить картинку по названию (id)

```
class PictureShower(Resource):
    def get(self, name):
        return f'''<html><img src="{name}"></html>''', 200
```

Сам файл с названием лежит в корне проекта, рядом с запускаемым файлом. Однако при запросе на нужный адрес я получаю вместо отрендериного html - строку с ней:

```
"<html><img src=\"44751a70-6795-4c02-8a35-c10fa5d4cbe8.jpg\"></html>"
```

Вот это выводит в окно браузера, просто текстом. Как сделать что бы браузер воспринял это как html страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Использовал всроеный в flask send file

```
class PictureShower(Resource):
    def get(self, name):
        return send_file(name, mimetype='image/png')
```